# Doubt in First Course in Probability by Sheldon Ross

Tags: probability, combinatorics, factorial

Here is the example that I was solving from the book on probability.

> A football team consists of $20$ offensive and $20$ defensive players. The players are to be paired in groups of $2$ for the purpose of determining roommates. If the pairing is done at random, what is the probability that there are no offensive-defensive roommate pairs? What is the probability that there are $2i$ offensive-defensive roommate pairs, $i=1,2,\ldots,10$?
>
> **Solution** There are
> $$\binom{40}{2,2,\ldots,2}=\frac{(40)!}{(2!)^{20}}$$
> ways of dividing the $40$ players into $20$ *ordered* pairs of two each. (That is, there are $(40)!/2^{20}$ ways of dividing the players into a *first* pair, a *second* pair, and so on.) Hence, there are $(40)!/2^{20}(20)!$ ways of dividing the players into (unordered) pairs of $2$ each. Furthermore, since a division will result in no offensive-defensive pairs if the offensive (and defensive) players are paired among themselves, it follows that there are $[(20)!/2^{10}(10)!]^2$ such divisions. Hence, the probability of no offensive-defensive roommate pairs, call it $P_0$, is given by
> $$P_0=\frac{\left(\frac{(20)!}{2^{10}(10)!}\right)^2}{\frac{(40)!}{2^{20}(20)!}}=\frac{[(20)!]^3}{[(10)!]^2(40)!}.$$

What I don't understand is why is the solution considering unordered pair for the calculation? Aren't we choosing sets without any permutation of elements within them? What are we over-counting here? Can someone explain what am I missing?

Comment: The unordered pairs are the room assignments. If I look at a list of who is in what room, it is a list of twenty unordered pairs.

Comment: I still don't understand . Can u elaborate please? Why are we dividing by 20!? :( @ndhanson3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the $20$ rooms and assign players to these rooms as follows:-

Choose two players for the first room in   $\begin{pmatrix}40\\2\\\end{pmatrix}=\frac {40\times 39}{2\times 1}$  ways.

Now choose for the next room from the remaining 38 players etc.

This gives the number $$\frac {40!}{(2!)^{20}}.$$

The rooms themselves can be arranged in $20!$ ways and this arrangement is irrelevant to the pairings so the answer is divided by $20!$ to obtain the number of pairings.

Comment: I think I got it. While making the pairs , we don't want to care which room we are assigning to a pair, so we divide by 20! because all of them are equivalent . Thanks :)

Comment: Great! I'm glad that helped.

Answer (score 2):

$\displaystyle \frac {\left(\begin{matrix}20\\2,2,...2\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}20\\2,2,...2\end{matrix}\right)/(10!)^2}{\left(\begin{matrix}40\\2,2,...2\end{matrix}\right)/20!}$

This is another way to think about it. Number of ways to pair up 20 people squared divided by the number of ways to pair up 40 people.